Excel refresh to import external data
I have a lot Excel files containing external data connections to a local database. I have sql queries to extract data. Since few weeks refresh is not working sometimes to one user.
I discovered what is the issue, it appear when user open Excel files and the option "refresh data at opening the file" is activated. If the query is automatically refreshed when opening the file, manually refresh is no more working after.
To solve this, users must uncheck the auto refresh option, save it and close all Excel files. I had the same issue to another user last week, if he repeated the same procedure few days, the issue disappeared.
Many other users are using the same files without any problem. Any idea what can be the issue?
Thank you,
Paul

